# missing figure toolbar and possible change in global variables

Tags: matlab, variables, global, uitoolbar

Today i tried adding a slider below my graph, so different graphs would be drawn when you slide it. Eventually i got all of this to work perfectly fine, however i still have two small issues.
On top of the figure with the slider, the figure toolbar is gone. It can easily be added by clicking view -> figure toolbar at the top in the figure itself. However to do this everytime is a bit tedious. And when i google'd for the problem, the results where are all guides to create custom toolbars. I just want to add the default toolbar back, it was fine. But i do not know how to do that. Typing 'uitoolbar' gives an empty one. But i am not sure how to fill it with the default icons.

And the second problem i ran into;
The main script calls in the end for a function, this function then creates the new graph with the slider. However herefore i needed to transfer the matrix of data to plot from the main script to the function, so i made the matrix a global variable. However as soon as the function is called, matlab gives me this error (once for each global variable):

```
> In xxxx at 270 
Warning: The value of local variables may have been changed to match the globals.     
Future versions of MATLAB will require that you declare a variable to be global before you use that variable.
```

Before i call the function i type

```
  global xL yL zL p
```

which are the data required to plot. Then the first line in the function file is this same line again. The data seems to be transmitted fine and the graph shows the correct plot.
Is this some error i can just ignore then? Since everything works as it should? Or what does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here are my 2 cents:

1) From what I understand the simplest way to fetch the toolbar would be using [findobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) and then make it visible:

```
hToolBar = findobj('Type','uitoolbar');
set(hToolBar,'Visible','on');
```

You can also get the toolbar's properties using "get". Here is what it looks like from a simple script I ran:

```
get(hToolBar)

hToolBar =

    0.1890 %// don't worry about that number; it's the handle for the toolbar.


    BeingDeleted = off
    ButtonDownFcn = 
    Children = [1.18896]
    Clipping = on
    CreateFcn = 
    DeleteFcn = 
    BusyAction = queue
    HandleVisibility = on
    HitTest = on
    Interruptible = on
    Parent = [1]
    Selected = off
    SelectionHighlight = on
    Tag = 
    Type = uitoolbar
    UIContextMenu = []
    UserData = []
    Visible = off
```

I don't know why it disappears though.

2) You might get rid of those global variables if you sent your data as inputs to your function is that a possibility?

For example:

```
function PlotData(xL,yL,zL,p)

%// Your code here
```

Hope that helps!